# Cycle through overlays

Tags: beamer, overlays

I have a frame of five overlays, and I would like to cycle automatically between them (until a \hyperlink button is pressed).

The way I'm currently doing that is replicating each overlay 100 times and adding a `\transduration{.6}` command, which naturally results in a long compilation time and a large PDF file.

Is there a more elegant way of doing that?

Comment: This is not a true solution but if you use `xsavebox` to store the contents of the repeating slides in saveboxes then the compilation time and the file size will get reduced. Other option may be to use the `animate` package. But each of these proposals is far from satisfactory.